# "Return to App" button in box's OAuth2 screen returns with an Error: invalid_client

Tags: ios, box-api

I've got the v2 API working in our iOS app, but have run into one issue with the login page that comes up. If a user taps the "Return to App" button, they get a page that says

```
Error: invalid_client
```

Under the **Show Error Details** disclosure it says

```
state=ok
```

Looking at the logs, it looks like tapping that link causes the view to try and load

```
https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?state=ok
```

Which then produces that screen. According to the v2 docs, we're supposed to leave the redirect_uri field in the app's entry on box.com's site empty. I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue, or whether I need to be doing something more in our app to handle that tap.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  We will be removing that shortly.